# Deploying a Safe locally ERROR: [SafeProxy was not deployed correctly]

Tags: hardhat, gnosis-safe, safe-core, account-abstraction

I Everyone !

I'm currently trying to deploy a safe using hardhat and Safe Protocol Kit SDK

Basically what I did was:

- Cloning the Smart contracts repo => Deploy them on hardhat local node
- Using the playground/protocol-kit/deploy-safe.ts

I changed the parameters to link the SafeFactory.create to my local node using that configuration

```
    const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
    ['31337']: {
      safeSingletonAddress: '0xC0bF47e15F557dB6f9B0e4997B27C7CDd24fB3fF',
      safeProxyFactoryAddress: '0x7Ec60b29C1c201C7F1C97C42e3edbA3E8f905360',
      multiSendAddress: '0xa552810048f47Fd6B27D56e15F4e3eD2eF3c5882',
      multiSendCallOnlyAddress: '0xD205976DE203ecebBEfC388c1b058c77B9344A0e',
      fallbackHandlerAddress: '0xf02dfD5568bC2149b6b5a119eEdBd76b100C3E82',
      signMessageLibAddress: '0xF247a2e2F0F124303dE37f75db8E0F5bA79D54eB',
      createCallAddress: '0xB22D635D552eC95142E2Abe3FfB859eA7d7C0316',
      simulateTxAccessorAddress: '0x38710E559A67ef07bcF8EeA70B076ac8e756DE08'
    }
  }
  const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter, contractNetworks })
```

The addresses here are of courses the ones that the

> npm run deploy-all custom

generated

Until here, everything seems fine but during the

```
 const safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
    safeAccountConfig,
    callback
  })
```

I correctly get the Predicted deployed Safe address and the Tx but after that the transaction revert due to a

> Error: SafeProxy was not deployed correctly

This error comes from SafeProxyFactoryEthersContract: line 62 and I can't know why this crash.

Is there a full documentation or tutorial explaining how to correctly locally deploy the safe contracts and create a safe using the SDK ?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

to use the SDK locally, you will first need to configure the [Safe Transaction Service](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/161191/deploying-a-safe-locally-error-safeproxy-was-not-deployed-correctly) for your own network. To run the [Safe Transaction Service locally](https://docs.safe.global/api-service-architecture#running-locally), you can follow [this guide](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md).

Let me know if it solved the problem! Best, Louis